# 文字列の後に続くパーセント記号（％）はどういう意味ですか？

Tags: python

下記のような`%`はどういう意味でしょうか？
`%s`は文字列を差し込むという意味かと思っているのですが`number=%s'`　の後の`%`はどういう意味ですか？

```
def dump(self):
    print('name=%s, symbol=%s, number=%s' %
         (self.name, self.symbol, self.number))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

文字列中の `%s` に差し込む値を渡すための演算子です。

詳しくは、公式ドキュメントの [printf形式の文字列書式化](http://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) を参照してください。